# Converting BaseType to Derived Generic Class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I need a little help with this.

```
public class DerivedMessage<T> : Message where T: MyClassBase
{
    public TestMethod();
    public T Item { get; set; }
}

public class MyClassBase
{
}

public class DerivedClass: MyClassBase
{
}

public class DerivedClass2: MyClassBase
{
}
```

Let's assume I have:

```
Message msg = new DerivedMessage<DerivedClass>();
```

Is there the possibility to convert it back to `DerivedMessage<T>` without knowledge about its template parameter?

So for example, create template with `MyClassBase` as template parameter:

```
DerivedMessage<MyClassBase> m = msg as DerivedMessage<MyClassBase>;
```

My goal is to receive access to `DerivedMessage` (for example `TestMethod()`) public methods which aren't dependent on the specified `DerivedClass`.

Edited !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your inheritance tree is wrong. In your example above `MyClassBase` is not the base for `DerivedMessage`, so the line `MyClassBase msg = new DerivedMessage...` shouldn't even compile.

I think you should put all the methods you need later into an interface that's implemented by `DerivedMessage`. The following works:

```
    private interface IMessage { void Test(); }
    private class Message { }
    private class DerivedMessage<T> : Message, IMessage where T : BaseClass { public void Test() { Console.WriteLine("Test"); } };
    private class BaseClass { }
    private class DerivedClass : BaseClass{};

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Message msg = new DerivedMessage<DerivedClass>();
        IMessage mess = msg as IMessage;
        mess.Test();
    }
```

The real question is: What keeps you from trying?

Comment: Yes I fixed that line. It should be Message msg = new

Answer (score 1):

Since you are stating there is no dependency to a certain `DerivedClass`, I would slightly change your design and encapsule the methods inside an interface

```
public interface IMessage
{
    void TestMethod();
}
```

and implement it in `DerivedClass`:

```
public class DerivedClass<T> : IMessage, Message
    where T : MyClassBase
{
    // ...
}
```

And then use an interface to communicate with your methods:

```
var message = (IMessage)msg;
message.TestMethod();
```

Cheers!